# How do you remove (unmap) a Test Case from Test Set with Rally REST API?

Tags: rally

How do you remove a Test Case from a Test Set in Rally, using the REST API?

It is intended to be called from JavaScript. I was unable to find the information in their documentation; a link would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Javascript - are you also using Rally's AppSDK? If so, it would be relatively straightforward to work up a simple AppSDK example that shows this - with the perks that AppSDK offers.

If you're using straight up REST, a gotcha is that Test Cases don't have a TestSet attribute field - the mapping is that Test Sets have a collection of Test Cases. The way to do it would be to query the Test Set via REST:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.34/testset/12345678910

Which will provide a response looking something like this (using XML for read-ability, recommend using JSON in practice):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestSet rallyAPIMajor="1" rallyAPIMinor="34" ref="https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.34/testset/1234741798" objectVersion="7" refObjectName=" Data Import Tests" CreatedAt="Mar 29">
  <CreationDate>2012-03-30T00:23:59.964Z</CreationDate>
  <ObjectID>1234741798</ObjectID>
  <Subscription rallyAPIMajor="1" rallyAPIMinor="34" ref="https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.34/subscription/1231154643" refObjectName="My Subscription" type="Subscription" />
  <Workspace rallyAPIMajor="1" rallyAPIMinor="34" ref="https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.34/workspace/1234498610" refObjectName="My Workspace" type="Workspace" />
  <Changesets />
  <Description>Tests to validate data import</Description>
  <Discussion />
  <FormattedID>TS11</FormattedID>
  <LastUpdateDate>2012-03-30T00:25:56.544Z</LastUpdateDate>
  <Name>Grid Data Import Tests</Name>
  <Notes />
  <Owner rallyAPIMajor="1" rallyAPIMinor="34" ref="https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.34/user/1234320127" refObjectName="My Username" type="User" />
  <Project rallyAPIMajor="1" rallyAPIMinor="34" ref="https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.34/project/1234731604" refObjectName="My Project" type="Project" />
  <RevisionHistory rallyAPIMajor="1" rallyAPIMinor="34" ref="https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.34/revisionhistory/1234741799" type="RevisionHistory" />
  <Tags />
  <Blocked>false</Blocked>
  <Iteration rallyAPIMajor="1" rallyAPIMinor="34" ref="https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.34/iteration/1234172067" refObjectName="Iteration 1" type="Iteration" />
  <PlanEstimate>2.0</PlanEstimate>
  <Rank>500000010240.000</Rank>
  <Release rallyAPIMajor="1" rallyAPIMinor="34" ref="https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.34/release/1234791788" refObjectName="Release 1" type="Release" />
  <ScheduleState>Defined</ScheduleState>
  <Tasks />
  <TestCaseStatus>SOME_RUN_SOME_NOT_PASSING</TestCaseStatus>
  <TestCases>
    <TestCase rallyAPIMajor="1" rallyAPIMinor="34" ref="https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.34/testcase/1234758065" refObjectName="Test Case 1" type="TestCase" />
    <TestCase rallyAPIMajor="1" rallyAPIMinor="34" ref="https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.34/testcase/1234757395" refObjectName="Test Case 2" type="TestCase" />
    <TestCase rallyAPIMajor="1" rallyAPIMinor="34" ref="https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.34/testcase/1234000782" refObjectName="Test Case 3" type="TestCase" />
  </TestCases>
</TestSet>
```

Which shows a collection of three Test Cases. To remove Test Case 3, you'd submit a REST request that only includes Test Case 1 and Test Case 2, as follows:

```
<TestSet ref="/testset/1234741798">
  <TestCases>
    <TestCase ref="/testcase/1234758065"/>
    <TestCase ref="/testcase/1234757395"/>
  </TestCases>
</TestSet>
```

This will update the Test Set such that it removes Test Case 3 and only has the first two Test Cases.

Your client-side code would need to loop through the REST response from the Test Set query, and construct a POST request that throws away the un-desired Test Cases and keeps the ones you want.

Comment: Thanks. That's very helpful. I guess there is no concurrency on Rally's end. If someone changed the test case list between the get and post, it's not going to resolve it.

Comment: Concurrency problems can definitely be an issue with large TestSets. I believe that AppSDK2 will have some benefits here as some of the data stores with that Javascript SDK will help manage concurrency conflicts.

Comment: Actually checked in with the development team, and AppSDK2 probably won't help much with the "top-down" type of collection attributes with TestSets - however, it will be useful for "bottom-up" updates like you see with a collection of Tasks on a User Story.