# Rally: How to add more testcases to a testset

Tags: java, rally, testcase

I am in a situation where there are already some testcases associated to a testset and I want to add more testcases to that testset. Looking at WSAPI, I can only add a collection of testcases to a testset. What if I have to add only one more testcase to a testset?
Currently, I am re-adding all testcases to the testset in form of a JsonArray?
I would prefer a way by which i can simply add one testcase to a testset, adding a collection of testcases to a testset every time can potentially be a risky way.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the answer to this question:

[How do you remove (unmap) a Test Case from Test Set with Rally REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231449/how-do-you-remove-unmap-a-test-case-from-test-set-with-rally-rest-api/11233375#11233375)

It's going the opposite direction, i.e. removing rather than adding Test Cases from a Test Set, however, it illustrates the same thing - unfortunately you have to update the entire collection.

Your approach with the JsonArray is correct. You are also correct that this is not without risk - concurrency issues can occur if a Test Case within the collection should change during the update operation on the Test Set.